# Is it possible to generate compiler/Resharper warnings for certain methods or parameters?

Tags: c#, automation, resharper, compiler-warnings

Our team works on a C# project and frequently, some of us use "wrong" methods or parameters, often unintentional. Two examples:

```
// would be better to use our extension method .AsString() which is more performant
var s = myEnum.ToString();
// keepSubscriberReferenceAlive is set to true and returned token is unused, so this is a potential memory leak
eventAggregator.GetEvent<PubSubEvent<IEventHandler>>().Subscribe(EventHandler, ThreadOption.UIThread, true);
```

Usually, someone stumbles over code like this, searches for other occurences, fixes them and sends a mail to the team saying "Don't ever do this again, because...".

But of course, having an automated way to detect things like this and generate warnings would be better. I know that Resharper warnings can be customized, but can it generate warnings on certain methods or parameters? Or is there some pure C# way to tell the compiler to generate warnings here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Resharper there is a tool called [**Custom Code Inspections**](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Code_Inspection__Creating_Custom_Inspections_and_QuickFixes.html).

Its easy to create. Just paste the part of your code in Search pattern.

Cover them with sign `$`. Resharper automatically creates placeholders. then write your desired code in replace pattern.

You can also edit placeholders if you need.

In your first example :

[image]

And in code Resharper suggests

[image]

Comment: Nice! Thanks so far, I'll give it I try and mark the answer correct if it works for us.